# Testing on iPad chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, testing

Is there any way to emulate iPad chrome?
I'm not talking about resolution alone. When i emulate resolution, everything works just fine. It's the chrome on iPad that shows crippled site (weirdly, safari is fine).
Ran out of trial time on device anywhere. 
Any software solution or some other service?
Thank you!